# Which Method is More Accurate?

Tags: java, floating-point

Suppose we implement the following two methods to calculate the `n`th multiple of a real number `x`.

```
public static double multiply( double x, int n )
{
    return x * n;
}

public static double iterativeAdd( double x, int n )
{
    double a = 0.0;

    for( int b = 0; b < n; b++ )
    {
        a += x;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Assume that `n` is a legal `int` and that both `x` and the exact mathematical product of `n` and `x` are no less in absolute value than `Double.MIN_VALUE` (unless both are `0.0`) and no greater in absolute value than `Double.MAX_VALUE`. Here's what I'm wondering: In general, which is closer to the exact value of the product of `x` and `n`: the `double` returned by `multiply( x, n )` or the `double` returned by `iterativeAdd( x, n )` and how do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for every floating point operation you do, your [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) increases. This happens because floating point numbers have a fixed size in memory, limiting their precision. Each operation is rounded to the nearest value that a float can represent. This rounding accumulates after a while.

Both numbers will get you very close to the answer, but if you run both methods on a large and varied set of numbers, you will see that on average `iterativeAdd()` has a greater distance from the actual value.

Additionally, `multiply()` will be significantly faster on any machine, so there's no benefit to ever using `iterativeAdd()`.

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge, the first method will produce more accurate result because in the second method after each addition probability that some of the digits will be truncated and rounded are more then a single multiplier operation as the result will be calculated once and then the digits will be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Both will return approximately the same value, however there is greater chance that the `iterativeAdd()` will return more inapproximate value, but the difference will be negligible.

Any single float operation results in some precision loss however small.

In `multiply()` you make use of the float operation only once but in `iterativeAdd()` you use it n times.

In general we should avoid using any function like `iterativeAdd()` as it is will take up a lot of processor time with `n` floating point operations.